# Can a person with a disability that causes them to be incontinent put on tefillin? If so, when?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, medicine, psych-mentalhealth, handicap-disabled-impair

If someone has a disability wherein they suffer from incontinence from time to time are they able to put on *tefillin* or not? Is there any consideration for psychological or emotional damage that may result from their inability to so?

NOTE: I am only intending URINARY incontinence here, nothing else. Thank you.

Please kindly cite your sources.

Comment: this seems like a case to case basis , see Shulchan Aruch 43:1 it may have an impact

Comment: I coulda sworn we had this question or one very like it. But I can't find it.

Comment: I know, I did a search before posting it and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**First**:

The *`Arokh HaShulhan*, *Hilkhoth Tefillin*, *siman* 43:1-14, explains the laws relating to bodily functions and the proper donning/treatment of *tefillin* at those times.

Although the Rambam appears to be more *mahmir* and only allows one to urine in his *tefillin* under duress or if he forgot and began to relieve himself (see there), the *Shulhan Arukh* (and the plain meaning of the *Gemara*) indicate that - *me-`iqqar ha-din* - it is permissible to urinate while wearing *tefillin* in certain permissible locations (again, see there). It seems that the *Hazal* made a *gezerah* against it lest someone come to defecate or flatulate while wearing them, activities which are expressly forbidden.

Thus, it would seem that the unintentional possibility of urinary incontinence would not prevent one from wearing *tefillin*, at least during a time when they do not expect it to be likely to experience such incontinence.

**Another approach**:

The *Gemara* in *b.Berakhoth* 22b (cf. Rambam, *Hilkhoth Tefillah* 4:10) indicates that if someone experiences urinary incontinence during the *Shemoneh `Esre* he simply needs to pause until it stops before continuing. However, various *Rishonim* discuss the implications - *le-qula* - if urine is contained, splashed on one's garment, and/or  covered by a clean, dry outer garment. Other *Rishonim* discuss this issue as well and most agree that urinary incontinence during one's *tefillah* is only a problem which requires action when one is aware of it and/or it drips or pools on the ground beneath him.

Thus, it would seem that a disabled person who wears an adult diaper could continue to pray even when experiencing known urinary incontinence, and all the more so when it is unknown.

What does this have to do with *tefillin*? Because the *iqqar* time to wear *tefillin* is during the *Shemoneh `Esre* (cf. Rambam, *Hilkhoth Tefillin* 4:26; *b.Berakhoth* 15a). And, since *Hazal* does not even mention the need to remove one's *tefillin* in a such a case of involuntary incontinence, it would appear that they are not concerned about it.

**Conclusion**:

So, *le-'aniytuh da`ati*, it would seem that - pending certain reasonable details and conditions - the answer to this question is: **MUTAR**