# Wearing Adult Diapers Voluntarily, for example on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, psych-mentalhealth

If an adult does not have a medical need to wear a diaper, but has some reason they would like to do so, for example if it helps with stress/anxiety, would there be a Halachic issue with doing so? For example, on Shabbat if a diaper is wet and you sit down, would there be problem with squeezing it?

There is obviously a lot of discussion about baby diapers, and I would assume most of that applies to an adult with incontinence, but how does that change if the reason is mental rather than physical:

- [color changing lines](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31137/34387)
- [tefillin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47593/34387)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Arik and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Perhaps this is considered an article of "clothing" for this person.